# CiviCRM Navigation Menu not displaying and UI is abnormal

Tags: display

Hi Fellows I am a newbie to drupal and civicrm
I have just installed CiviCRM(5.48.1) on Drupal 9(hosted on Azure Linux VM).
But I found out my navigation menu is missing and the UI is set a drupal style.
I have tried on clearing caches and reset paths as advised by other posts, however it doesn't work. Do you gys have a clue on this? Happy Holidays!
[image: HomePage]

[image: Admin Pages]
[image: Drupal Appearance Page]

Comment: Use your browser's Developer Tools and see whether there are any errors for CSS/JS that the page tries to load.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm having the same problem and can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Any clue to this issue? Same problem here...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server has write permissions to /web/sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute

Comment: Also write permissions to /web/sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn